# How to implement SearchView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, searchview

I wrote the following code :

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        Log.d("Tab", "SearchManager: " + searchManager + " : " + searchView);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    }
}
```

----------------------------EDITED-------------------------------------

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

---

Code in menu.xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

When I run my code, It throw NullPointerException at

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
```

It means I got null value at

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

Exceptions are :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ushatek.pustakbazaar.fragment.TabFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(TabFragment.java:168)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:2047)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2125)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentController.java:270)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:299)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:243)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:448)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have go through each questions of SO. But am still stuck.

Comment: Make sure you are inflating correct menu xml.

Comment: Am pretty sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with provided inflater instead of

```
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

this statement may be like following...

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

And Second thing is to override `onCreate()` of Fragment and write  `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` It should be like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Hope it will help.